# Connected my domain to a bucket on google cloud and getting bucket does not exist error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I connected my domain to serve  static content by linking it to a bucket on google cloud , however I am getting the following error message when i type the website address on the browser

`NoSuchBucket`
The specified bucket does not exist.

Any help in resolving the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082411/gcp-static-website-returns-error-nosuchbucket perhaps? www vs. non-www mismatch?

Comment: Thanks! it works now. I think the issue came over because the documentation says to enter domainname.com...maybe the documentation in google cloud should be improved.

Comment: Can you link which document were you following? It might be necessary to get it updated. Thanks!

Comment: That document was from cloud.google.com, are you from google?

Answer (score 1):

For documentation, the suggested solution on the Stack Overflow post is:

> You just needed to add www. to the beginning of the bucket name.
>
> In other words: www.domain.com instead of domain.com

Comment: Thanks, exactly the same problem I had. The example that Google presents in the text field is a domain WITHOUT the 'www'. I am sure a LOT of people are getting the same error